# How do I make a graphics change place randomly everytime I click on it

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics, mouse

The code I made won't change the coordinates of the ball every time I click on it.

```
public class AimTrainerPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
    
    static final int WIDTH = 1300;
    static final int HEIGHT = 750;
    static final int SIZE = 10;
    Random rand;
    JLabel cd;
    int x;
    int y;
    boolean running = false;
    Timer timer;
    
    AimTrainerPanel() {
        rand = new Random();
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.addMouseListener(this);
        startGame();
    }
    
    public void startGame() {
        newDot();
        running = true;
        timer = new Timer();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        draw(g);
    }
    
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        if (running) {
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillOval(x, y, SIZE, SIZE);
        }
    }
    
    public void newDot() {
        x = rand.nextInt((int)(WIDTH/SIZE)) * SIZE;
        y = rand.nextInt((int)(HEIGHT/SIZE)) * SIZE;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        int mx = e.getX();
        int my = e.getY();
        if (mx >= x && mx <= x + 10) {
            if (my >= y && my <= y + 10) {
                newDot();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }
}
```

The newDot() method is suppose to create new coordinates every time it is called but the ball won't change places. I don't know if it's because I misswrote something or because my what I did doesn't change the coordinates or if I'm suppose to add something.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what your Timer is supposed to be doing, but it doesn't appear to be a Swing Timer, and since this is a Swing GUI I'd get rid of it.

Now to the crux of your problems:

- You're using `mouseClicked` which isn't called if the mouse moves *even slightly* between mouse pressed and mouse released, and so often it is better to use `mousePressed` or `mouseReleased` methods and not `mouseClicked`
- You don't call `repaint()` after changing the state of your program. Swing won't know that a repaint is needed unless you suggested, and so in your mouseListener or in code called by it, you should call this method after changing GUI state.  Here you can call it at the end of the `newDot(...)` method or in the mouse listener after you call the same method.
- Your if blocks within your mouse listener appear to be quite restrictive as to where they will allow the listener to respond to a mouse click -- is it too restrictive? I don't know since I'm not familiar with your requirements, but possibly.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I can't accept my own answer. If this comment is for the OP, then it may need to be placed on the question so that they see it. Thanks!

Comment: *"If this comment is for the OP,"* It is. *"then it may need to be placed on the question so that they see it."* Nope. the rules of when someone gets notified of comments or answers are a little complicated, but for the OP it's simple. They get notified of every comment on any answer or the question, tagging anyone (or no-one). As an aside, they asked a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68279644/418556), but I won't give it much thought unless they improve that one in line with the comments, and accept an earlier answer to show they can work out how to, and are *willing* to.